# Angle that makes a segment's size be one third of the circle

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

The point O is the center of the circle with radius 1, and the points A and B are the points on the circumference. If the shaded segment is one third of the size of the circle, what's the value of $\theta = \angle OAB?$ I tried by subtracting the area of the triangle $OAB$ from the sector, however it ends up as an equation $\sin 2\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}-2\theta$ and I can't know how to solve this kind of equations. Any help in solving the equation or the question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With $\theta$ both inside and outside a trig function, the equation is [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation), with no solution in elementary functions. The best you can do is use numerical methods to approximate the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need numerical methods to approach an exact solution. But it is very easy to obtain a relatively tight bound on $\theta$.

Simply rewrite your equation as

$2\theta+\sin2\theta=\pi/3$

and observe that the $2\theta$ piece must be larger than the $\sin2\theta$ piece. So

$2\theta>\pi/6$

$\sin2\theta<\pi/6$

Solving these inequalities gives

$\pi/12<\theta<(1/2)\sin^{-1}(\pi/6)$

$15°<\theta<15°48'$

(The minutes in the upper bound are rounded up to assure it's an upper bound. The actual solution, rounded to the nearest minute, is $15°22'$.)